# Writing a File object to a file in java

Tags: java, file

For a class, I have to send a file of any type from my client to a server. I have to handle each packet individually and use UDP. I have managed to transfer the file from the client to the server, and I now have a file object which I cannot figure out how to save to a user specified directory.

```
f = new File(path + '\\' + filename);//path and filename are user specified.
FileOutputStream foutput = new FileOutputStream(f);
ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(foutput);
output.writeObject(result);//result is a File
output.flush();
output.close();
```

Any time I run this code, it writes a new file with the appropriate name, but the text file I am testing ends up just containing gibberish. Is there any way to convert the File object to a file in the appropriate directory?

EDIT: As it turns out, I was misunderstanding what, exactly, a file is. I have not been transferring the data, but rather the path. How do I transfer an actual file?

Comment: "now have a file object which I cannot figure out how to save to a user specified directory" .. Are you asking "How do I copy a file?" ?

Comment: I suspect you are misunderstanding what `File` and `ObjectOutputStream` do.  Reread the documentation.

Comment: Using Serialization like you do is writing a binary file that represents the object - human cannot "read" it. It sounds like what you're looking for is a JSON/XML representation of your object which could be written to a file - so that a human can read it. Lookup "marshalling and unmarshalling objects in java"

Comment: Did you transfer a `File` object, or the bytes the file contains?

Comment: I converted the file to a series of byte arrays and sent them. I reassembled the byte arrays and converted it back to a File object using a custom class I found called ByteUtils.

Comment: I can't see why you'd need any class called "ByteUtils" to write byte array data to a file. Maybe you should show how you're creating the `result` object.

Comment: The Client makes an ArrayList of packets to send.
        `file = BytesUtil.toByteArray(f);
        for(int x = 0; x < file.length; x++){
         pack[x%256] = file[x];
     if(x % 256 == 255 || x == file.length - 1){
      header = destIP + "\n" + destPort + "\n" + x / 256 + "\n" + BytesUtil.toString(pack);
      temp = header.getBytes();
      packet = new DatagramPacket(temp, temp.length, address, gremPort);
      packets.add(packet);
     }
    }`

The Server extracts the data from each packet and adds it to a string called file.
    `result = (File)BytesUtil.toObject(file.getBytes());`

Comment: Sorry for the mess above. I have no idea how to edit comments to look nice.

Comment: It's not quite clear from that whether you're encoding & decoding the transmitted data correctly. But anyway, all you need to do to save the data is open a FileOutputStream and call its .write method with each received byte array. See @BruceLee's answer below for an example of using it.

Answer (score 3):

ObjectOutputStream is a class that outputs a specific format of data to a text file. Only ObjectInputStream's readObject() can decoding that text file.
If you open the text file , it is just gibberish ,as you have seen.

you want this:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + '\\' + filename);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(result);
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];    
int hasRead = 0;
while((hasRead = fis.read(buf)) > 0){
    fos.write(buf, 0, hasRead);
}
fis.close();
fos.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, how about using a `FileWriter`?

```
File result = new File("result.txt");
result.createNewFile();
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(result); 
writer.write("Hello user3821496\n"); //just an example how you can write a String to it
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Comment: I have to be able to transfer a file of any type. This only works with text files, correct?

Comment: That requirement was not clear from your question, but from the API: "FileWriter is meant for writing streams of characters. For writing streams of raw bytes, consider using a FileOutputStream."  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html